# Ionic / Angular : Firebase Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been using firestore for a while. Everything is fine with the database and the rules except for an entity, the collection is named "Matches". On some items of this type (not all of them are concerned, which is even more disturbing), the user permissions do not seem to be sufficient:
The rules are the following in firebase rules :

```
  match /Matches/{matchItem} {
        allow read, create: if isAuth(request);
        allow update, delete: if isOwner(resource.data.idUser);
  }


  function isAuth(request) {
      return request.auth != null;
  }

  function isOwner(idToCheck) {
      return request.auth.token.id_auth_user == idToCheck;
  }
```

Please note that i added a custom property (token.id_auth_user) to request.auth to avoid passing by the uid.

The same user can however modify other items with exactly the same rules si i do not think the problem is comming from the isAuth(request) or the request.auth.token.id_auth_user. The idUser is filled in my object so i don't see where the problem can be. The idUser specified is the good id.

Here is the structure of the object I want to modify :

[image]

The call in my angular code is as follows:

```
    return this.afs.collection("Matches/").doc(match.id).update(match)
        .then()
        .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

And i got this error in chrome console :

> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Does anyone have a way to avoid this error?

Comment: To start with, is it not meant to be `request.auth.uid`? Check [this Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth). Then there are many questions one can ask to solve the issue but I think you should try to simulate the rules from the Firebase console Rules Play ground with expected auth and data. [This Firebase Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator) mentions how to do so

Comment: Yes you are right, but my token.id_auth_user is a custom property i added. I will update my question with this information. Thanks.

Comment: Also remove the trailing slash in the collection name inside the Angular code. You should have `.afs.collection("Matches")` instead of `.afs.collection("Matches/")`. Infact I feel this should be the solution

Comment: Unfortunaly it is not, the '/' is ignored and the result is the same with ou without.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, i leave the questions / awnser here is someone made the same miskake as i have :

The object I send is well formed in his new version, but the old object I want to update in the database is not and do not have is id.

As I use the resource.data and not request.data (which seems to me more secure, because the data of the request can be modified by the user); the id checked is the one of the object in database and not the one I try to send.

The solution is therefore upstream, to properly form my object well before sending it to the database.